# Server usage topped 100% and crashed - how to diagnose and prevent

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cpu-usage, server-crashes, attacks

I'm running a small webserver on Ubuntu 12.04.

Last night, the server topped off at 100% cpu usage and crashed. This is unusual as I'm normally around 1-5%. I suspect a DDoS attack from someone related, but I'm not certain. I searched apache logs, syslog, messages, fail2ban logs but I couldn't find anything that explains what happened.

How can I figure out the cause of the crash?
How can I possibly prevent it?

Comment: Have you considered hiding it behind cloudlare to start with?

Comment: I have not. CloudFlare isn't something I've used before. The thing is I'm not sure it's an attack...

Comment: Start by moving the site through cloudflare - they do some serious things there and that may help. It is a simple DNS change, free of charge.

Comment: I will give it a shot, thanks. Having multiple vhosts on the same domain isn't an issue or anything?

Comment: No, they intercept via IP and then come as a proxy - works like a charm and save you some bandwidth, too, but mostly they block certain attack vectors. Only impact is analytics - web server logs do not get every visitor (google analytics etc. does)